# Replace html element with jquery not working

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery to modify html elements from http response from jquery. The element in html was indeed modified but immediately returned to original content - looks like the page was refreshed. Please give some suggestions. Here is my code.

```
<form action="" method="get" id="test_form">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" >

     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-btn" onclick="submit_jquery()" value="">
    </div>
 </form>

<p id="p_test">123</p>

//// js code
function submit_jquery() {

    var i =0;

    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        async: false,
        url:"http://127.0.0.1:80",
        data:{source: i},
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data){
            j = JSON.stringify(data);
            $("#p_test").replaceWith(j);

        },
        error: function(){

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The page must be reloading because the type of button is **submit**

You can change it to

```
<input type="button">
```

which will stop it from refreshing page

Comment: It's a `form` element, why should the button be of type `button`? The type `submit` is correct

Comment: "submit" would refresh the page. Use button works. Thank you!   another workaround is event.preventDefault().  Could someone post the code?

Answer (score 1):

As you are handling the submission via jQuery/Ajax, you need to handle the form `onSubmit` event and return false so that the normal form submission(which reloads the page) is cancelled.

Try this

```
<form action="" method="get" id="test_form" onSubmit="return false">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to `return false` after the ajax. It prevents the page from redirecting.

```
function submit_jquery(){
    // your code here

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with forms always listen for the `form`'s submit event rather than for the `submit` button's click event. Both events do fire but when you focus on the button's click event you're not able to stop the form's default action when it's `submit` button is clicked. I would therefore take the following approach:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#test_form').on('submit', function(e) {
    //stop form from submitting (defaut action)
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var i =0;

    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        async: false,
        url:"http://127.0.0.1:80",
        data:{source: i},
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data){
            j = JSON.stringify(data);
            $("#p_test").replaceWith(j);

        },
        error: function(){

        }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="get" id="test_form">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" >

     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-btn" value="SUBMIT">
    </div>
 </form>

<p id="p_test">123</p>
```